# How to center RelativeLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to center a `RelativeLayout` which contains `TextViews` in a `ScrollView` but when I change to Landscape mode or even in portrait mode with a small screen, the button of the `RelativeLayout` is cutted... Have you any idea to center it without be cutted please??

Here my code:

```
    <ScrollView
    style="@style/scroll"
    android:background="@drawable/first_body_shape" >

    <RelativeLayout style="@style/relativeLay"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rg2"
            style="@style/verset"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rg1"
            android:text="@string/rg_2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rg3"
            style="@style/textView_intro"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rg2"
            android:text="@string/rg_2_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rg4"
            style="@style/verset"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rg3"
            android:text="@string/rg_3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rg5"
            style="@style/textView_intro"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rg4"
            android:text="@string/rg_3_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rg6"
            style="@style/verset"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rg5"
            android:text="@string/rg_4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rg7"
            style="@style/textView_intro"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rg6"
            android:text="@string/rg_4_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rg8"
            style="@style/textView_intro"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rg7"
            android:text="@string/rg_5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rg1"
            style="@style/textView_intro"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/rg_1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

styles.xml

```
    <style name="scroll">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">50sp</item>
    </style>

     <style name="relativeLay">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>

 <style name="verset">
    <item name="android:layout_width">370sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Comment: whats that style refers to? can you please add styles.xml...

Comment: where are android:layout_width="wrap_content"          android:layout_height="wrap_content" properties for relative layout and textviews, if you have done something in style please share with us

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your problem (i don't see any button in your code :o).
But have a look on this tutorial :

http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/